# Is my project idea possible under current available technology?

Tags: android, c++, nfc

Basically, I've had to come up with a 9-month project for my final year at university, and I've wanted to do something that incorporates the use of NFC and most likely Android devices. The project itself doesn't require to be entirely completed in the time, with good reasoning.

The concept I have thought of is to produce two seperate pieces of software, a Windows-based C++ application and a paired Android application which communicate via an NFC connection, using a USB NFC device.

The purpose of this would be to act as a form of remote for the PC, such as media controls, sleeping and waking the PC etc.

I would use something such as this: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Andoer-ACR122U-Contactless-Reader-Writer/dp/B00KX00WLE/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1441900306&sr=8-1&keywords=ACR122U for the connection, and the SDK provided by the developers https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3g3az3e7k1kfpo/H10391.zip

My question is just whether anyone, preferrably with some experience in at least a related area, would be able to enlighten me as to whether they think this would be possible?

Thanks for any help in advance, 
Stephen

Comment: Remote means 'at distance' while NFC is for very short range (<20 cm). Just making sure you understand that different technologies (NFC, BLE, Bluetooth, WiFi, Cellular) have different ranges.

Comment: NFC and *remote* doesn't exactly sound like the perfect match.

Comment: Apologies, poor word choice there I think, what I mean is to have the device resting on the NFC pad, where it would then be used. The aim for me isn't to produce a massively viable commercial application, but more of a proof of concept.

Comment: Recently what's popular for digital cameras is to use NFC to initiate a WIFI connection. After the WIFI connection is established, the hand held device can remotely operate the camera. Requiring the remote client(the hand held device) to stay on a NFC pad has little value compared with one connected by a cable. However, remote desktop through WIFI or wired Ethernet is well supported since a long time ago. I personally tried it a few years ago, with Windows 6.5 client and Windows Server 2003 host successfully, without using any third party software.